# which fork debugger to use?

Tags: hardhat, contract-debugging

what tool are you using to debug mainnet contracts. So doing a fork and be able to step into line by line (considering you have the source ofcourse), but doing it on live contract.
I tried to use solidity debugger pro for visual studio code, but no luck setting it up, I get some strange errors.